# Automate Node-JS-Server on IBM i

Tags: node.js, ibm-midrange

i wrote a little Server with node.js on our ibm i.
To start the server i have to run this command:

```
5250> qsh
$ node /home/node/server.js
```

How can i automate this or run the Server with a CL-Script and how can i stop the Server then ?

thanks jo

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way is to do it in a CL Program like this:

```
         ADDENVVAR  ENVVAR(QIBM_MULTI_THREADED) VALUE(Y)          
         MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0000)                                
         QSH        CMD('sh -c /myNodeDirectoryInIfs/myShellScript.sh')
```

Your shell Script may look like this then:

```
#!                                 
cd /myNodeDirectoryInIfs/dist/build   
node myNodeScript.js
```

To start it, you can do a SBMJOB on the above CL Program.
To End it, you need to end the submitted Job.

A better way of course is to use a Process Manager like pm2 for example.
If you are still interessted in doing that, please leave a comment.